# Automation of Class Creation based on User Input

Tags: python, class

So in python, there's the `getattr` function to automate getting attributes of a particular class, fair enough.

What I am trying to do is create a class from a user input, similar to how I could loop through class attributes using `getattr`.

Here's the process that I am sort of thinking of:

```
# Define classes that the user could chose
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1 = 'hi'

# Define other classes

className = input()  # The user would then type a class name like Person
newObj = className()  # I would want this to evaluate like Person()
```

Basically, I'm trying to not make my code look like a bunch of

```
if className == "Person":
    newObj = Person()
elif className == "Dog":
    newObj = Dog()
```

Basically, is there any built in function where I can refer to a class through a string?

Comment: You really shouldn't make your user input connect to implementation details, like the *class name*, in your program. Instead, you should create *some explicit mapping* from strings to classes, take user input as string, then retrieve the class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both classes' `__init__` take the same arguments, the simplest way is with a mapping dict. My example below involves a cheeky error handling, which you can avoid if you split the second line into several.

```
mapping_dict = {'Person': Person, 'Dog': Dog}
instance = mapping_dict.get(user_input, lambda: print('Invalid class name'))()
# instance is None if an invalid input was provided
```

Without the cheeky error handling:

```
mapping_dict = {'Person': Person, 'Dog': Dog}
class_obj = mapping_dict.get(user_input)
if class_obj:
    instance = class_obj()
else:
    print('Invalid class name')
```

Comment: Thank you for that. One sort of follow up question, that kind of applies this to a more extended case: is there a way to automate this mapping? Like, if I have a parent class, and I use parent.__subclasses__() to get n number of subclasses, can I automatically link the subclass name to the execution of its class like you explained using mapping_dict?

Comment: @hijinx85 see my answer - it is a dynamic one.

Comment: @balderman dynamic, but a bad design. It binds user-facing input to implementation details (class names)

Comment: @hijinx85 You can get the list of subclasses, but you should not automatically bind the class names to the required input. If you happen to change a class' name the usage will be affected

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry for so many questions, as I am a rather beginner python-er! Why would we not want to bind user-facing input to implementation? Is it to make our code more robust and less likely to break? If you do change the classes name, wouldn't you have to rerun the code anyways, and the get_classes() would reset itself, or is there something else I'm missing (which is quite possible)

Comment: @hijinx85 but then your *users* would have to care about the *internals of your program*. That is *fundamentally bad design*. You design a *contract*, like "enter the  string Person". That doesn't have to change just because you class is now named `Agent` instead of `Person` or whatever stylistic refactor that shouldn't matter to the user, or what if you refactor to *not use a class at all*?

Comment: @hijinx85  Imagine you are the **user** of the program you are making and you know that typing `'Dog'` gives you a dog. Then you, as the **developer**, change the class name to `DogV2`. The **user** would still expect `'Dog'` to work. But it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory design pattern:

```
class CAR(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a car"


class BUS(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a bus"


class TRAIN(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a train"


def create_vehicle(vehicle_type):
    target_class = vehicle_type.upper()
    return globals()[target_class]()


vehicles = ['bus', 'car', 'train']
for v in vehicles:
    print (create_vehicle(v))
```

Output would be :

```
This is a bus
This is a car
This is a train
```

There is another metaclass based solution, though, it might be overkill for this simple requirement.

```
_registry = {}


class MetaClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, methods):
        super().__init__(clsname, bases, methods)
        _registry[cls.__name__] = cls


class CAR(metaclass=MetaClass):

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a car"


class BUS(metaclass=MetaClass):

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a bus"


class TRAIN(metaclass=MetaClass):

    def __str__(self):
        return "This is a train"


def create_vehicle(vehicle_type):
    target_class = vehicle_type.upper()
    return _registry[target_class]()


vehicles = ['bus', 'car', 'train']
for v in vehicles:
    print (create_vehicle(v))
```

Comment: Well, Python is not Java... You don't really need the `VehicleFactory` class

Comment: @soumya-kole that doesn't make any sense. Just use a function as your factory, `class VehicleFactory` is pointless.

Comment: Made the changes.

Answer (score -2):

A dynamic approach below

```
import sys, inspect


def get_classes():
    return {name: obj for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) if inspect.isclass(obj)}


class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Person ..')
        self.prop1 = 'hi 0'


class Student():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Student ..')
        self.prop1 = 'hi 1'


classes_mapping = get_classes()
user_input = input('Type class name:')
clazz = classes_mapping.get(user_input)
if clazz:
    obj = clazz()
else:
    print(f'Unknown class {user_input}')
```

Comment: This is bad design, as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested. If for some reason the implementation is changed (= the classes names) then the end user is going to be affected by that

Comment: why use `inspect` here?? `inspect.isclass` should just be `isinstance(obj, type)` and `inspect.getmembers` should probably just be `globals()`